# RecyclerView Adapter methods not called

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, adapter, android-recyclerview

I have this weird issue with my adapter that no methods are called.. The constructor works, it stops there if I have a breakpoint but from there, nothing.. `onCreateViewHolder` doesn't get called and neither `onBindViewHolder` and not even `getItemCount`.. I tried everything I could find online but nothing seems to be working so I don't know what to do. Any suggestions? Here's my code:
Fragment:

```
public class FragmentPackageDetails extends Fragment {
    //other vars
    RecyclerView rvPackageDetails;
    DatabaseHandler database;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        String temp = args.getString(KEY_TRACKER_CODE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_package_details_new, container, false);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        rvPackageDetails = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvPackageDetails);
        rvPackageDetails.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        database = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
        selectedPackage = database.getPackage(trackerCode);

        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new MyAdapter(selectedPackage.getRecords());
        rvPackageDetails.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    //other methods in class
}
```

MyAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<TrackingRecordCheckedOut> mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView tvPackageDetailsRowDayOfWeek, tvPackageDetailsRowDayOfMonth, tvPackageDetailsRowNameOfMonth,
                tvPackageDetailsRowDetailsTitle, tvPackageDetailsRowDetailsDescription, tvPackageDetailsRowDetialsTime;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            tvPackageDetailsRowDayOfWeek = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPackageDetailsRowDayOfWeek);
            tvPackageDetailsRowDayOfMonth = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPackageDetailsRowDayOfMonth);
            tvPackageDetailsRowNameOfMonth = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPackageDetailsRowNameOfMonth);
            tvPackageDetailsRowDetailsTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPackageDetailsRowDetialsTime);
            tvPackageDetailsRowDetailsDescription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPackageDetailsRowDetailsDescription);
            tvPackageDetailsRowDetialsTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvPackageDetailsRowDetialsTime);
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(ArrayList<TrackingRecordCheckedOut> myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_list_item, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        TrackingRecordCheckedOut tr = mDataset.get(position);
        holder.tvPackageDetailsRowDayOfWeek.setText(tr.getDayOfWeek());
        holder.tvPackageDetailsRowDayOfMonth.setText(tr.getDayOfWeek());
        holder.tvPackageDetailsRowNameOfMonth.setText(tr.getMonthOfYear());
        holder.tvPackageDetailsRowDetailsTitle.setText(tr.getTitle());
        holder.tvPackageDetailsRowDetailsDescription.setText(tr.getDetails());
        holder.tvPackageDetailsRowDetialsTime.setText(tr.getTimeOfDay());

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

}
```

Fragment Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvPackageDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerView Row Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llPackageDetailsRecyclerViewRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="96dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPackageDetailsRowDayOfWeek"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="3"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPackageDetailsRowDayOfMonth"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="4"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPackageDetailsRowNameOfMonth"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="3"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPackageDetailsRowDetailsTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPackageDetailsRowDetailsDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPackageDetailsRowDetialsTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure that `selectedPackage.getRecords()` is not returning an empty list?

Comment: Yes.. I have 4 items inside it

Comment: Try to move the code inside *onViewCreated()* to *onCreateView()* ( instantiation of the RecyclerView, creation of the adapter...)

Comment: I tried it... Still no luck.. I moved everything from my fragment to a testing activity and I haven't had to change anything and it worked.. I just adapted the code form a fragment to activity and works perfectly.. I can't figure out why.. I think I'll just live it like this directly inside the actiity..

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue where neither onCreateViewHolder or onBindViewHolder were being called. Saving a reference to Context in the constructor of your Adapter, and then changing your onCreateViewHolder method to use the saved reference to Context instead of doing parent.getContext() should fix it:

```
private Context mContext;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TrackingRecordCheckedOut> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
    mContext = context;
}

public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view using saved reference to Context (mContext)
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_list_item, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code don't really see an issue unfortunately. One thing that might be problematic is that in you ViewHolder constructor you call super(v). You might need to call super((LinearLayout)v). That might not make a difference though.

Good luck!